# javafx on client side

Tags: java, javafx

Do the clients need something else than a proper jdk and javafx compliant browser to visit javafx applets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX is based on download able JARs. I think there are multiple runtimes, but all of them Require JRE 1.6. The JavaFX classes will be loaded by the WebStart or Applet Classloader, so the JRE does not need to provide this extension.

However as there are some new Features of Java 6 Update 10 specifically targeted for rolling out JavaFX applets, it is most likely that this is the best choice. Update 10 has a [new Java Plugin](https://jdk6.dev.java.net/plugin2/) with improvements in speed, installation and stability, and it allows quicker initial installation.

The following JNLP Samples with fine with the released Java 6u10:

http://javafx.com/htdocs/samples.html
http://a.stritzinger.googlepages.com/jfxrace

Comment: Ok, thanks for this information. All the samples where "standalone" applications that run "outside" the web browser (a new program was launched, you had to download it and accept some signatures/certs). Is it possible to run the applets inside a browser?

Comment: Here is an instruction how to build them: http://jfx.wikia.com/wiki/Applet_Example and here are some sample applets - and yes its laggy and not seemless, not sexy.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks for this information. All the samples were "standalone" applications that run "outside" the web browser (a new program was launched, you had to download it and accept some signatures/certs). Is it possible to run the applets inside a browser? (more transparency for my client)

Answer (score 1):

JavFX can be run as an applet and the Java plug-in for running applets was rewritten for Java 6ul10 to provide a better experience for everyone for the JavaFX release.

You can see plenty of applet examples at JavaFX.com as well as the samples in the Netbeans 6.5 JavaFX plugin.